# jQuery ajax get call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my ajax call, I'm simply trying to display the json from my php file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

PHP (phonecall.php):

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','mydb');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"mydb");
$sql="SELECT * FROM incoming_calls";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $callArray[] = array('phonenumber' => $row['phone_number'], 'id' => $row['phone_login_id']);
    echo json_encode($callArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Phone calls</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "phonecall.php",
  data: "",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response){
  $("#call").html(response);
  }
});
</script>

<div id="call"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing displays in my div tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the array many times, just do it one time only, check your console in order to check it the response is correct.

```
$callArray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $callArray[] = array('phonenumber' => $row['phone_number'], 'id' => $row['phone_login_id']);        
}

mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($callArray);
```